# How do I perform this query the smartest way possible?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity

Basically I got the following tables:
**UserProfile** - includes a UserId and a UserProfile named Referer
**Lead** - Includes a UserProfile (FK) named Owner

What I'm looking to do is to get all the leads of all the referrals of a particular userprofile.

I was thinking of the following process:
Get all the referrals of the userprofile
For each referral, get all the leads where the owner matches the referral.

How could I perform this (or possibly smarter) with LINQ to entity?

I've been messing with the following:

```
var referrals = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.Referer.UserId == UserId);
            var allLeads = db.Leads.Include("Owner").Where(l => true);
            List<Lead> totalLeads = new List<Lead>();
            if (referrals.Any())
            {
                foreach(UserProfile u in referrals.ToList())
                {
                    var leads = allLeads.Where(l => l.Owner.UserId == u.UserId);
                    if (leads.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (Lead l in leads.ToList())
                        {
                            totalLeads.Add(l);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 1 (`referrals.Any()`) + 1 (`referrals.ToList()`) + 2 * number of referrals (`leads.Any()` and `leads.ToList()` for each referer) separate database queries. You should be able to get the result with a single database query. I think this one for example should do it:

```
List<Lead> totalLeads = db.UserProfiles
    .Where(u => u.Referer.UserId == UserId)
    .Join(db.Leads, u => u.Referer.UserId, l => l.Owner.UserId,
        (u, l) => new { Lead = l, Owner = l.Owner })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.Lead)
    .ToList();
```

The strange looking `AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Lead)` is necessary because you cannot use `Include` when joining entities. EF will ignore the `Include`. By projecting the `Lead` and `Lead.Owner` into the anonymous type EF will load both and EF's relationship fixup will populate the `Lead.Owner` property in the result collection correctly.